# field initialization in Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I want to create a field containing vectors. My field contains 1 row and 1000 columns which each columns contains a vector which have 1 row and 100 columns.

So I write the following code to create my data structure:

```
field<frowvec> x(1,1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    x(i) = frowvec(1,100);
}
```

The above is working, but I want to set vectors' size in field initialization and remove the for loop. Is there a way to do this?

Best Regards,
Reza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field class has the .fill() member function:

```
field<frowvec> x(1,1000);

frowvec blank(100,fill::zeros);

x.fill(blank);
```